# HTML form through PHP to Excel / .csv

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form, like survey and have a PHP file with this code

```
<?php
$fieldA = $_POST["prezime"];
$fieldB = $_POST["ime"];
$fieldC = $_POST["datumrodjenja"];
$fieldD = $_POST["mestorodjenja"];
$fieldE = $_POST["rod"];
$fieldF = $_POST["prebivaliste"];
$fieldG = $_POST["brojpasosa"];
$fieldH = $_POST["izdatod"];
$fieldI = $_POST["vazido"];
$fieldJ = $_POST["profesija"];
$fieldK = $_POST["zanimanje"];
$fieldL = $_POST["fiksni"];
$fieldM = $_POST["mobilni"];
$fieldN = $_POST["email"];
$fieldO = $_POST["napomena"];

$keys = array($fieldA,$fieldB,$fieldC,$fieldD,$fieldE,$fieldF,$fieldG,$fieldH,$fieldI,$fieldJ,$fieldK,$fieldL,$fieldM,$fieldN,$fieldO); //THIS IS WHERE YOU PUT THE FORM ELEMENTS ex: array('$fieldA','$fieldB',etc)
$csv_line = $keys;
foreach( $keys as $key ){
    array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]);

}
$fname = 'prijave.csv'; //NAME OF THE FILE
$csv_line = implode(',',$csv_line);
if(!file_exists($fname)){$csv_line = $csv_line."\r\n" ;}
$fcon = fopen($fname,'a');
$fcontent = $csv_line;
fwrite($fcon,$csv_line);
fclose($fcon);
?>
```

The problem with this code is that it creates .csv file, but with no more than 2 rows. When 2 rows are filled with informations from the form, no more collecting.

And the second question, how to allow š ć đ č letters to be collected from the form via this script? Thank you!

Comment: You might want to have a look at [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks for help Patrick, the main problem is that I'm not a PHP programmer, so learning articles do not help. I'm a UI designer but I have to finish this, so If anyone can help me to implement fputcsv() to my code that would be great!

Comment: We're here to help those who are willing to help themselves.  If you're not going to take the time to read the documentation to learn how to use the appropriate function for what you're looking to do, then most people here aren't going to take the time to help you.  Show some effort.  It will go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar requirement for a project I was working on. I came up with this small function to write an array to a CSV file ( Comma Delimited ).

I used the [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php/%22fputcsv()%22) function which is pretty handy.

The function accepts 2 arguments, the array name as well as the name you would like the CSV file to be called. Using the fopen, i open the an empty file in the directory where I want to save the CSV file.

I set the header if I need one and write that out to the file.

I then loop through the array and output each element and delimit it by a ",".

Once done, I close the file.

I understand this may not answer your full question, but I believe this will help you in someway.

If your array looks like the same format as the one below, Then the function I have provided will work.

**Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Doe
    [2] => England
    [3] => Somewhere
    [4] => Something
    [5] => UK
    [6] => Foo
    [7] => Bar
    [8] => Yes
    [9] => Developer
    [10] => Stack Overflow
    [11] => No
    [12] => 0123456778
    [13] => johndoe@gmail.com
    [14] => Smith
)
```

**Function**

```
<?php


//Change these strings back to what you need
$fieldA = "John";
$fieldB = "Doe";
$fieldC = "England";
$fieldD = "Somewhere";
$fieldE = "Something";
$fieldF = "UK";
$fieldG = "Foo";
$fieldH = "Bar";
$fieldI = "Yes";
$fieldJ = "Developer";
$fieldK = "Stack Overflow";
$fieldL = "No";
$fieldM = "0123456778";
$fieldN = "johndoe@gmail.com";
$fieldO = "Smith";

$array = array( $fieldA,$fieldB,$fieldC,$fieldD,$fieldE,$fieldF,$fieldG,$fieldH,$fieldI,$fieldJ,$fieldK,$fieldL,$fieldM,$fieldN,$fieldO );


//set the filename 
$filename = "prijave";

//call the function and pass the above array and filename as arguments
array_to_csv( $array, $filename );


//function to write array to csv file using fputcsv()
function array_to_csv( $array, $filename ) {

    //open the csv file
    //set the path for the file - use a+ to set file pointer to end of file
    $out = fopen( "/path/to/output/directory/".$filename.".csv" , 'a+' );

    //header - optional, remove if not needed
    $header = array( "Column 1 Name","Column 2 Name","Column 3 Name","Column 4 Name","Column 5 Name","Column 6 Name",
                     "Column 7 Name","Column 8 Name","Column 9 Name","Column 10 Name","Column 11 Name","Column 12 Name",
                     "Column 13 Name","Column 14 Name","Column 15 Name"

              );

    //write the header - optional, remove if not needed
    fputcsv ( $out, $header, "," );


    //foreach loop is if you have a multidimensional array- uncomment if it is
    //foreach( $array as $line ) {

        //write each line of the array to csv file
        fputcsv( $out, $array, "," );

    //}

    //close the file
    fclose( $out );

}

?>
```

I have tested the above code and it works as it should. I have a header that is written to the file, along with the values from the array beneath each column.

[image: CSV Output]

Comment: Thanks for the help Ibrahim, the main problem is that I'm not a PHP programmer. I tried to change your code for my needs but unsuccessful. I have to finish this, so If anyone can help me to implement fputcsv() to my code that would be great!

Comment: @kuzmvnovic Can you do a `print_r( $keys );`  under your array and post the output in your original question?

Comment: but the output is text from the inputs (what I typed) when I do print_r( $keys );

Comment: @kuzmvnovic I have updated my answer. Please read it thoroughly and adjust to your needs if necessary.

Comment: Just one thing, when you submit the form first time, everything is okay, but when you submit the form again, it replaces the old info (from the first time). :/

Comment: @kuzmvnovic that's because the filename has been set to a static string. I will update the code to use the filename+the year,month,day,hour,minute,second. Eg. Prijave_20180413204805.csv - this way the filename will always be unique and will not overwrite it.

Comment: @kuzmvnovic check updated answer. The filename will always be unique and will not get overwritten the next time you run it.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but I need informations from inputs to be collected in one csv file but different rows. When User1 submits the form, it goes to the first row, when User2 submits the form, it goes to the second row, etc. Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: @kuzmvnovic Oh right, sorry I didn't know what you wanted exactly. I have removed the `$date` variables and changed the fopen from W to a+. It should now append to the same file instead of creating a new file or truncating the existing file

Comment: thanks for that. I tried the code and everything is okay except the header applies every time when the form is submitted. So the CSV file looks like - 1st row = header, 2nd row = inputs data, 3rd row = header, 4th row = inputs data. How to put the header just on the first row, and all other rows to be data from inputs? Also, is there an option to force UTF-8 encoding because of special characters? Thank you!

Comment: @kuzmvnovic In that case, you can hardcode the header into the CSV fiile and the comment out the code `fputcsv ( $out, $header, "," );`. The code will no longer put the header in.